# Generating thumbnails using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

How to generate a thumbnail of any website using javascript or jquery?

I couldn't find any right match for my requirements.

```
  <div id="generate_thumbnail" onclick ="generate();">
  //Show thumbnail within this div
  </div> 

  <Script>
   function generate()
   {
        // generate small thumbnail
   }
```

Comment: Why does your `generate()` doesn't take any URL as argument? Do you mean to thumbnail the own website where the script is running?

Answer (score 6):

A thumbnail of a website? Such as a miniature browser-screenshot? Sorry, this can't be done without of some sort of external browser-screenshot service:

http://www.zubrag.com/articles/create-website-snapshot-thumbnail.php

Comment: How about generate an iframe and then embed the code within it

Answer (score 3):

Try some thumbnail generation services with API.

http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/10-free-website-thumbnail-generation-services/

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but this is not quite doable with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

At best you could change the  to an  and try to impose some external CSS to give it a `zoom` level to shrink down the content. But otherwise there's no way for Javascript to render a page, convert it to an image, and stuff it into another page.

Answer (score -1):

Try using the [qTip JQuery plugin](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/download/).